# upgrading boost version

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I'm using RHEL 5.3, shipped with gcc 4.1.2 and boost 1.33.
So, there's no boost::unorded_map, no make_shared() factory function to create boost::shared_ptr and other features available in newer releases of boost.

Is there're a newer version of boost compatible with the version of gcc?
If yes, how the upgrade is performed?

Comment: just install the newest version, you can follow steps here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578499/how-to-install-boost-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Download the latest version (1.43.0) of the Boost libraries from [the Boost website](http://www.boost.org/) and follow the steps in [the getting started guide](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/more/getting_started/index.html), which explains how to build Boost on a number of platforms, including Linux.

Answer (score 4):

Simply [download](http://www.boost.org/users/download/) and [install](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html) the newest version; it will adapt itself automatically to your compiler.

Comment: Not sure if that's correct. I just downloaded and installed 1.58 and `cat /usr/include/boost/version.hpp | grep "define BOOST_LIB_VERSION"` still yields 1.54?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just download the latest source from [link text](http://boost.org).  If you are only using header only libraries, it just needs to be unpacked.  If you are using one of a handful that require a library, you will need to build those.