# How to install Boost on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, boost

I'm on Ubuntu, and I want to install Boost. I tried with

```
sudo apt-get install boost
```

But there was no such package. What is the best way to install Boost on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1134, accepted):

You can use `apt-get` command (requires `sudo`)

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

Or you can call

```
aptitude search boost
```

find packages you need and install them using the `apt-get` command.

Comment: do you have any past experience with boost?

Comment: I had programming experience with boost, but not installation experience. I have never tried this myself, so I can't say if it is easy to use (but it seems to me that package manager is the easiest way). I should have posted this suggestion as a comment, but I can't comment questions.

Comment: You can try this [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-453691.html), but I think there should not be any problem, you just install with aptitude and then start using boost

Comment: The one disadvantage of using apt-get is that it is usually a couple of version behind the latest boost release.

Comment: can you suggest another way by which the "" mismatched versions of Boost.Build engine and core"" can be sorted out?

Comment: It is easy to build and install Boost from the sources, for example http://anycoder.wordpress.com/2014/04/28/building-boost/

Comment: Great it worked like a charm, is there any way to install specific package of boost, for example I want to install only boost/asio.h  and its dependencies, is there any way to achieve that

Comment: I had that and still get .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `boost::python::throw_error_already_set()'

Comment: I think have to mention that to install a particular library you need to enter the following command:
aptitude install libboost_library_name

Comment: It seems it doesn't work - I ran the command `sudo apt-get install libboost-filesystem1.55.0`, but only libraries are installed, not headers. `#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>` or `#include <boost/filesystem>` complains about missing file.

Comment: Do not use the packaged version of boost, right now on Ubuntu 16.04 it's 1.58, and the latest stable version is 1.67.0 !
See the response and my comment below : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41272796/2617716

Comment: plz keep in mind this will install ALL packages in boost, something like `8 upgraded, 274 newly installed, Need to get 192 MB of archives. After this operation, 724 MB of additional disk space will be used.`, you can install only needed ones

Answer (score 261):

Get the version of Boost that you require. This is for 1.55 but feel free to change or manually download yourself:

```
wget -O boost_1_55_0.tar.gz https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.55.0/boost_1_55_0.tar.gz/download
tar xzvf boost_1_55_0.tar.gz
cd boost_1_55_0/
```

Get the required libraries, main ones are `icu` for `boost::regex` support:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential g++ python-dev autotools-dev libicu-dev libbz2-dev libboost-all-dev
```

Boost's bootstrap setup:

```
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/
```

Then build it with:

```
./b2
```

and eventually install it:

```
sudo ./b2 install
```

Comment: What will be the difference if we use ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/include   ? I have the boost library in /usr/include. I was wondering that by doing this, can I replace my old installation ?

Comment: what is libboost-all-dev ? why should I install boost before installing boost?

Comment: @tbc0 Boost is at version 1.59 now, and the latest PPA is at 1.55, so building from source is relevant

Comment: building from source is a great exercise anyways, there's no harm if they're interested in trying, and as the top answer here already showed how to use the package manager, it's nice to have another answer show an alternative method.

Comment: How do we verify the version to ensure it installed correctly at the end? I just compiled & did `./b2 install` on Boost v1.66.0 but running `dpkg -s libboost-dev | grep 'Version'` says I have version `1.54.0.1ubuntu1`--probably because that's what was previously installed via `sudo apt install libboost-all-dev`

Comment: @javapowered If some program will try to install some boost headers/files, it will override lastest ones and create hell.

Comment: `sudo ./b2 install` builds it as well. You don't have to call `./b2` beforehand.

Comment: this is nice but it screws up cmake

Comment: @BenB To install somewhere else. Also, consider using the `--show-libraries` and `--with-libraries=library-name-list` options to limit the long wait you'll experience if you build everything. Finally.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the installation step. Where do you find these in the Boost website?

Comment: worked for me on my Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: It worked for me, thanks. But now I need to uninstall it again to test something with the default boost for my system. I tried `sudo ./b2 install` and `sudo ./b2 remove` without success. Is there a b2 target for uninstalling?

Answer (score 104):

**Installing Boost on Ubuntu with an example of using `boost::array`:**

Install libboost-all-dev and aptitude:

```
sudo apt install libboost-all-dev

sudo apt install aptitude

aptitude search boost
```

Then paste this into a C++ file called `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>

using namespace std;
int main(){
  boost::array<int, 4> arr = {{1,2,3,4}};
  cout << "hi" << arr[0];
  return 0;
}
```

Compile like this:

```
g++ -o s main.cpp
```

Run it like this:

```
./s
```

Program prints:

```
hi1
```

Comment: There is an error in the line "boost::array<int, 4> arr = {{1,2,3,4}};", it should be "boost::array<int, 4> arr = {1,2,3,4};"

Comment: why do i want to run `aptitude search boost`?

Comment: adding "<< endl;" to the"cout" line was required to flush the buffer and make my output show when running in a terminal.

Answer (score 37):

Get the version of Boost that you require. This is for 1.55 but feel free to change or manually download yourself [(Boost download page)](https://www.boost.org/users/history/):

```
wget -O boost_1_55_0.tar.gz https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.55.0/boost_1_55_0.tar.gz/download
tar xzvf boost_1_55_0.tar.gz
cd boost_1_55_0/
```

Get the required libraries, main ones are icu for boost::regex support:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential g++ python-dev autotools-dev libicu-dev libbz2-dev
```

Boost's bootstrap setup:

```
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local
```

If we want MPI then we need to set the flag in the user-config.jam file:

```
user_configFile=`find $PWD -name user-config.jam`
echo "using mpi ;" >> $user_configFile
```

Find the maximum number of physical cores:

```
n=`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "cpu cores" | uniq | awk '{print $NF}'`
```

Install boost in parallel:

```
sudo ./b2 --with=all -j $n install
```

Assumes you have */usr/local/lib* setup already. if not, you can add it to your *LD LIBRARY PATH*:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "/usr/local/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf'
```

Reset the ldconfig:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: Some things such as PO Edit 2.0 require boost 1.6, which is not available at this time via apt-get 
 you can get this from http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_60_0.html and then expand it. 

Follow the excellent instructions above, remembering that LD Library Path is not the same as $PATH

Comment: Please change the link to HTTPS; HTTP isn't safe for binary downloads :)

Comment: Comment from a recent installation, to get the latest version :
- Go to https://www.boost.org/ and "Current release" downloads to get the last one (currently 1.67.0 : https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.67.0/source/boost_1_67_0.tar.gz)

Thanks !

Comment: haha this screws up my system for good.   i think it's the last 2 items.

Comment: old link to sourceforge is not working. use https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.72.0/source/boost_1_72_0.tar.gz (with needed version)

Comment: That helped me with adding Boost 1.74.0 for including boost/math/interpolators/catmull_rom.hpp to ROS Melodic.  I get a ton of deprecated messages from ROS headers, but it works for what I need.  Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

An update for Windows 10 Ubuntu Application via Subsystem (also works on standard Ubuntu):

You might have problems finding the package. If you do, never fear! PPA is here!

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:boost-latest/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

Comment: OP didn't ask for Win10.

Comment: I'm aware, posting for those (Like me) who were looking for a rounded solution. Similar to Алексей Штыков's Answer

Comment: @AdrianW this answer isn't about Windows 10. It's about [Ubuntu that happens to be running on a Windows 10 kernel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10), so it's a valid solution to those running Ubuntu in some way. Since the question didn't limit it to Ubuntu running on a Linux kernel specifically, this solution is fine.

Comment: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/boost-latest/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.

Comment: Not to necro, but another point was brought up in another solution, which being that Packaged versions can be dated compared to source-compiled versions. If you use my solution, I'd follow the same advice which is to check if the version packaged fits your needs/enviroment.

Comment: I am having following erro: `E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/boost-latest/ppa/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.`

Answer (score 12):

**You can install boost on ubuntu by using the following commands:**

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install libboost-all-dev`

Answer (score 10):

First try the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libboost*
```

You may get an error message similar to the following, like I did:

```
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then try install below package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

Now you can create a a sample project utilizing Boost:

```
$ mkdir boost
$ cd boost/
$ cat > main.cpp &
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually you don't need "install" or "compile" anything before using Boost in your project. You can just download and extract the Boost library to any location on your machine, which is usually like `/usr/local/`.

When you compile your code, you can just indicate the compiler where to find the libraries by `-I`. For example, `g++ -I /usr/local/boost_1_59_0 xxx.hpp`.

Comment: This would only work for header libraries of boost. The rest of them would need to be built or installed using a package manager as described in the above answers.

The boost libraries that require separate building and installation are the following: atomic, chrono, container, context, coroutine, coroutine2, date_time, exception, filesystem, graph, graph_parallel, iostreams, locale, log, math, mpi, program_options, python, random, regex, serialization, signals, system, test, thread, timer, type_erasure, wave.

Comment: Even repairing this solution by following Elias Kouskoumvekakis's further instructions would be a bad idea (unless you have a good reason), since package managers add the ability to very easily update Boost to newer versions (in Ubuntu, just a `sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade` to upgrade **all** your packages to the latest versions in the repositories) if you find the appropriate package repository for Boost and to very easily delete Boost from the system if you want to. The manual approach makes those tasks harder, so you need a good reason to skip out on the benefits of a package manager.

Comment: Also, installing without a package manager is better covered in [an earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24086375/7208029), which includes necessary building instructions.

Answer (score 3):

Install libboost-all-dev by entering the following commands in the terminal

Step 1

Update package repositories and get latest package information.

```
sudo apt update -y
```

Step 2

Install the packages and dependencies with -y flag .

```
sudo apt install -y libboost-all-dev
```

Now that you have your libboost-all-dev installed
source: https://linuxtutorial.me/ubuntu/focal/libboost-all-dev/

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for any small guides - how to install boost latest release in Rocky Linux, however the same guide applies for any Generic Linux (CentOS, Ubuntu, Debian, Rocky, Fedora)

1. Download and extract the latest Boost release, inside the folder

```bash
sudo ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr
sudo ./b2 install --with=all
```

Check Boost version with

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include <boost/version.hpp>

int main(){

 std::cout << "Using Boost "     
          << BOOST_VERSION / 100000     << "."  // major version
          << BOOST_VERSION / 100 % 1000 << "."  // minor version
          << BOOST_VERSION % 100                // patch level
          << std::endl;

          return 0;

}
```