# Linux beginner, Where to put boost libraries?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, fedora

I'm not extremely familiar with the linux filesystem, having moved from windows, but I do have a decent amount of experience with C++ and the Boost libraries in windows.  Having switched Fedora 17, can anyone tell me if there is a certain directory where I should install Boost to get it working the gnu compiler?

Note: if it matters, I don't use an IDE I use vim for most of my programming.

Comment: anywhere as long as it's in the gcc include path.

Comment: Its better if you install it from GUI software repos in Fedora 17.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use your package manager to install boost libraries, for debian ubuntu it is like:

```
sudo aptitude install libboost-system1.49.0-dev
```

for centos6 it is

```
yum install boost-devel
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question of where to put the files when the package manager is not a viable option.

Comment: @User1291 yes, because if you want to answer this, you need to know much more about environment user has. This is why distros exists/

Answer (score 16):

There are a few ways of setting up the boost libraries on linux.

1. Save yourself some pain, use your package manager to install the Boost libs. You'll be grateful in the long run.
2. If you absolutely must do it yourself, simply put it anywhere so long as it's in the gcc include path. This is `/usr/local/include/` or `/usr/include/` for headers and `/usr/local/lib/` or `/usr/lib/` for libraries
3. Finally if for some reason that isn't possible, use the -I switch with g++ to specify the path to boost. (but this would only be necessary if 1 and 2 aren't possible)

Comment: Can you elaborate on 1) please ?

Comment: Which linux distro are you running?

Comment: then you can do something like `sudo apt-get install boost` done :)

Comment: I meant the "you'll be grateful" part. But that's ok, I guess I can find out by myself.

Comment: Oh -- mostly that you get updates for free and there's mutch less of a chance of you screwing up a build. Plus little to no path config

Comment: For the next person who winds up here: right now, the apt-get package is `libboost-all-dev` ( re: @jozefg's comment ).  [see also here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578499/how-to-install-boost-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

I had issues installing boost using yum (recently installed Fedora 17)..
so I unzipped the boost tar ball to my */opt*.

so `g++ -I /opt/boost/boost_1_51_0` works like a charm.

Comment: Did you adjust your PATH? If so, what did you add?

Comment: @Vérace no path adjustment required. Notice I'm passing the complete path to g++.

Answer (score 0):

From the introduction to boost:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html

you can put it anywhere you like. And then you compile with something like this

```
c++ -I path/to/boost_1_51_0 example.cpp -o example \
   -L~/boost/stage/lib/ -lboost_regex-gcc34-mt-d-1_36
```

"`c++`" can be `g++` or `clang++` for example.