# Installing pyvlfeat on Windows: cannot find -lboost_python-mt-py26

Tags: python, boost-python, vlfeat

I'm trying to install pyvlfeat on python in Windows. For installing this module,  I had to install `boost.python`. I installed and compiled the boost with `bjam --with-python toolset=gcc --layout=tagged`

After this I tried to install pyvlfeat by `python setup.py install` but at the end of the building process error showed up `cannot find -lboost_python-mt-py26`.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using data taken from [here](https://github.com/dsteinberg/imdescrip):
For pyvlfeat, change the setup.py entry:

LinkArgs = ['-msse', '-shared', '-lboost_python-mt-py26']

to

LinkArgs = ['-msse', '-shared', '-lboost_python-mt-py27']

then run python setup.py install

Answer (score 0):

you may need to install boost.python first
[how to install python.boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578499/how-to-install-boost-on-ubuntu)

or if you have installed boost.python,you may do as follows:

change setup.py

LinkArgs = ['-msse', '-shared', '-lboost_python-mt-py26']

to

LinkArgs = ['-msse', '-shared', '-lboost_python-py26'] or

LinkArgs = ['-msse', '-shared', '-lboost_python-py27']

(-pyxx depends which version of python your installed)

then run:(sudo) python setup.py install