# Python Dlib installation error : Could not find Boost

Tags: python, boost, dlib

When I try to install Dlib using `pip install Dlib` in command prompt Windows 10, it gives an error which says that it "cannot find Boost" even though I have compiled it and set the `BOOST_ROOT` and `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` paths.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36431669/error-compiling-dlib-could-not-find-boost) from @Kyle.

As he said,

> After you've compiled Boost, you need to do a couple things so that DLIB can find Boost. First, I set two environment variables,
>   BOOST_ROOT and BOOST_LIBRARYDIR.  I did this in the command window
>   before I compiled DLIB, though you could also pass these two variables
>   to CMAKE before running the build for DLIB. Something like:
>
> ```
> set BOOST_ROOT=c:\Program Files\boost set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR=c:\Program Files\boost\stage\lib
> ```
>
> Make sure you've built boost (and that second folder exists). I'm not
>   sure if this is necessary, but you could add those two to your path
>   just to make sure.
>
> `set PATH=%PATH%;%BOOST_ROOT%;%BOOST_LIBRARYDIR%`

I expect it helps.