# Can't install the "Boost" prerequisite for Caffe

Tags: python, boost, compilation, shared-libraries, caffe

I'm getting into machine learning, and I recently happened upon this:  [Wide-Area Image Geolocalization with Aerial Reference Imagery](http://cs.uky.edu/~scott/research/deeplyfound/)
.

It's a net that predicts the GPS location of an image, from just the image. Needless to say, I was thrilled, only to discover that one of the requirements:

```
import glob
import caffe
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import defaultdict
```

was Caffe, which I can't seem to install, because I can't install the main prerequisite: [Boost](http://www.boost.org/)

I first tried to run the standard `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`, which not only failed:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libboost-all-dev : Depends: libboost-chrono-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-date-time-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-filesystem-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-graph-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-graph-parallel-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-iostreams-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-log-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-mpi-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-mpi-python-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-program-options-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-python-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-regex-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-serialization-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-system-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-thread-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libboost-wave-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

It gave me a "but it is not going to be installed" error. I then tried to install from source:

```
wget -O boost_1_55_0.tar.gz http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.55.0/boost_1_55_0.tar.gz/download
tar xzvf boost_1_55_0.tar.gz
cd boost_1_55_0/
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local
./b2
```

And that promptly filled up my entire terminal with g++ errors. I then tried to start from scratch:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove libboost-all-dev libboost-dev libboost-doc
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libboost1.54-dev
```

And while that *worked* with the *test script*:  [How to Install boost on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578499/how-to-install-boost-on-ubuntu)

When I tried then to `make` caffe, I got this:

```
CXX src/caffe/util/db.cpp
In file included from ./include/caffe/common.hpp:19:0,
                 from ./include/caffe/util/db.hpp:6,
                 from src/caffe/util/db.cpp:1:
./include/caffe/util/device_alternate.hpp:34:23: fatal error: cublas_v2.h: No such file or directory
 #include <cublas_v2.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/util/db.o] Error 1
```

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't think it is a Boost problem but a Caffe one !

It's been already reported that For Caffe installation, Make sure to `set CPU_Only := 1` In your `makefile.config` as the following :

```
# CPU-only switch (uncomment to build without GPU support).
CPU_ONLY := 1
```

This is due to your `device_alternate.hpp` having the following :

```
line  4: #ifdef CPU_ONLY
line 32: #else
line 34: #include <cublas_v2.h>
line 99: #endif
```

Comment: OK, so where it says "`# CPU-only switch (uncomment to build without GPU support)`" do I uncomment both lines, or only one?

Comment: Don't forget accepting the answer if it solved you original question. Thanks