# cmake command can't find boost libraries

Tags: c++, boost

I'm using an ubuntu terminal to run a `cmake .`
But, the boost libraries couldn't be found.

```
  The following Boost libraries could not be found:

          boost_program_options
          boost_signals
          boost_serialization
          boost_unit_test_framework
```

With commands like:

```
cmake . -DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON
```

The problem persist, also, if I use a `location boost_unit_test_framework` I'm not getting any result.

How I can install those references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use apt-get command (requires sudo)

`sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`

[How to Install boost on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578499/how-to-install-boost-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to install all Boost libraries, you can install selectively what you need.

For example,  for boost_unit_test_framework you can do:

```
sudo apt install libboost-test-dev
```

And the others would be:

```
sudo apt install libboost-program-options-dev libboost-serialization-dev libboost-signals-dev
```