# Updating Boost library in ubuntu

Tags: boost, ubuntu-14.04

My machine is an ubuntu 14.04 with ROS.

when I do :

```
$ dpkg -s libboost-dev | grep 'Version'
Version: 1.54.0.1ubuntu1
```

Now that I need to work with later versions (mainly 1.62)of Boost, I followed the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24086375/5836291), Boost 1.62 is installed but getting the boost version as above returns the same old `1.54.0`.

Do I need to do anything else, so my system will point to the new 1.62 version ?

So the result to be is this :

```
$ dpkg -s libboost-dev | grep 'Version'
Version: 1.62.0.1ubuntu1
```

Thanks.

Comment: it is time to learn how to build debian packages by yourself %)

Comment: Great help thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you're installing a newer version of Boost outside dpkg, then dpkg obviously won't be aware of the new version (hence why running dpkg libboost-dev still points to the old version).

If Boost compiled/installed with no problems, then you just need to link the Boost libraries at compile time for whatever binary you're working on.