# How to install Boost.Python using pip on Windows 10?

Tags: python-3.x, boost-python, dlib

I want to install boost.python for the installation of dlib library.

Comment: FYI, now you can simply install **dlib** using pip as follows: `pip install dlib`

Answer (score 1):

You have to compile it for the platform. I believe PIP alone cannot accomplish that feat. You'll have to navigate the arcanery of bjam and boost build. God speed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe pip is able to do that (at least not yet).

If you want to avoid learning the boost build system and tools (b2, previously bjam), pre-compiled boost libraries can be installed via an executable:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/

This installs all Boost libraries, including Boost Python, and will use the default Python installation to build Boost Python unless you modify PATH first.

The link seem to only provide Windows executables. For other operating systems, similar solutions probably exists. Here is one for ubuntu: [How to Install boost on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578499/how-to-install-boost-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score -3):

Following command worked for me,

```
pip3 install boost
```

Comment: I really don't think OP was looking for a way to [boost automatically toots from users of the Mastodon social network](https://pypi.org/project/boost/) ;)