# Error in make cdec

Tags: makefile

I am trying to implement text generator of [JAMR](https://github.com/jflanigan/jamr/tree/Generator). It redirects me to install cdec. I followed [this](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~mdenkows/cdec-realtime.html) tutorial to install cdec. BUT

I installed gcc-4.8 (I had a better version 5.x but I thought 4.8 is neccessary). So I installed gcc-4.8 using [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/271561/319946). And I build Boost using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24086375/2374691) (in `~/prefix/sw`), I used boost_1_58 because it was latest. Everything worked fine.

Coming back to the tutorial, instead of `cd ~/prefix/sw` I went to `cd jamr/tools/cdec` where my cdec is present. Did `autoreconf -ifv` and `./configure --prefix=/home/student/prefix`, fine till now (I just had to comment line 216 of  containing `boost_major_version` and wrote `boost_major_version="158"`). But when I do `make` after a while I get

```
libtool: link: g++ -std=gnu++11 -fPIC -g -O3 /usr/lib /usr/lib -o reconstruct_weights reconstruct_weights.o  -L/usr/lib libutils.a -ldl -lrt -lboost_program_options -lboost_regex -lboost_serialization -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lz -lbz2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib: File format not recognized
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:836: recipe for target 'reconstruct_weights' failed
make[2]: *** [reconstruct_weights] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/student/ATS/jamr/tools/cdec-2014-10-12/utils'
Makefile:480: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/student/ATS/jamr/tools/cdec-2014-10-12'
Makefile:410: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tried `sudo make`, simple `./configure` and `make clean;make`. No help. [This](https://pastebin.com/VPrsAWHt) is make file.

Comment: Please post the relevant Makefiles. Most likely a variable is not set, which should have been set.

Comment: My system is stuck in login loop at startup, once I solve that I'll post the make files. I remember there were 3, I posted 1 of them above.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the `cdec` folder and you try to execute the commands there according to the instructions, we see that you get the `collect2 error: error: ld returned 1 exit status`. In the cdec folder, i **initially** execute the command:

`gcc -std=gnu99 -Wall -Werror -g array_product.c -o array_product -I../../ZDK -L../../ZDK -I../../TestLib04 -L../../TestLib04 -ltestlib04 -lzdk -lncurses -lm`

After this command, the error is solved and i get to the file and it says:

`> First, you need all the build dependencies, and the fastest way to install them all is this command, which installs not only the compiler but the additional boost libraries and Flex that you'll need. sudo apt-get install build-essential libboost-all-dev cmake flex`

`> Secondly, create a directory and go into it (you said ~/prefix/sw in your comments).`

`> Thirdly, git clone` https://github.com/redpony/cdec.git

`> Fourthly, you probably did not read the README page on the GitHub repository which explains what commands to run to make the software build. It lists these as the build steps, after cd-ing into the newly created cdec folder.`