# How can I get apt-get to install latest version of Boost

Tags: boost, wsl-2, apt-get

I'm trying to build a package that requires version 1.73 or higher of Boost. When I run
`sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev` the version that gets installed is 1.71, even though the current release listed on [boost.org](https://www.boost.org/) is [1.80](https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_80_0.html). I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2.

I've done a purge and remove, but a subsequent install again gets 1.71. When I repeat the apt-get without removing Boost first, then apt-get notifies that `libboost-all-dev is already the newest version (1.71.0.0ubuntu2)`. I also tried doing a `sudo add-apt-repository universe` but this didn't make a difference either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this same problem, unless someone corrects me (please tell me there's a better solution), the only solution is to download it and install it yourself from [the Boost libraries](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html).

For version 1.80, it looks like this:

```bash
wget https://boostorg.jfrog.io/artifactory/main/release/1.80.0/source/boost_1_80_0.tar.gz boost_1_80_0.tar.gz
tar -xf boost_1_80_0.tar.gz
cd boost_1_80_0
sudo ./bootstrap.sh
sudo ./b2
sudo ./b2 install
```

Other places where I've found people talking about this issue:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24086375/8705841
- https://linux.how2shout.com/how-to-install-boost-c-on-ubuntu-20-04-or-22-04/
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/670924/how-to-install-boost-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't have enough reputation yet to upvote your answer, but will do so in the future. In my case, I was also able to workaround the issue by developing in a container, from which apt-get did get the latest version.

Comment: Wait really @JanSmits? When I use apt-get inside Docker containers it still only gets like 1.71, and I haven't been able to find a container base that comes with Boost pre-installed

Comment: Well, I should clarify: apt-get doesn't get the actual latest version in my container, but it does get a later version. It gets 1.74 to be exact, which is sufficient for my requirement. My container is built off of `nvidia/cuda:11.7.1-devel-ubuntu22.04`.